# How to disable OneDrive on SP 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, onedrive

How can I disable OneDrive for Sharepoint 2016?

I mean:

1. Hide "OneDrive" button in left top corner.
2. Disable "Sync" button in all Document Libraries for all sites.
3. Do not let the desktop client to connect to OneDrive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can use a bit of CSS on master pages.

```
/* Hiding OneDrive */
.o365cs-nav-appTile[id='O365_AppTile_Documents'] {
    display: none;
}
```

Taken from https://thomasdaly.net/2017/02/24/branding-hide-newsfeed-onedrive-andor-sites-from-the-waffle-for-sharepoint-2016/.

2) I believe you can navigate to the site `/_layouts/15/srchvis.aspx` and disable offline client functionality.

3) Not directly possible (i.e. you're taking the obscurity route of this feature).

You could simply prevent users from provisioning OneDrive sites via permissions within the User Profile Service Application.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give more info about simply option with "User Profile Service Application" please?

Comment: If you go into the UPSA, you can go to Manage User Permissions and remove the right 'Create Personal Site'.